# Unable to generate access token from grant token in zoho

Tags: zoho

I have registered the application and generate `clientId`, `clientsceret`, code from the application.

I have configured and initialize it but unable to generate access token.

This is my code:

```
ZohoOAuthClient client = ZohoOAuthClient.GetInstance();
string grantToken = "1000.fd54383a88527ee4a9dfd589f4bba161.95bdbba47dffb77a5d830b2561b2d7a3";
                ZohoOAuthTokens tokens = client.GenerateAccessToken(grantToken);
                string accessToken = tokens.AccessToken;
                string refreshToken = tokens.RefreshToken;
```

I'm getting error of **"error": "invalid_code"**

Comment: authorization-code expire quickly (1 minute), so be careful with that

Comment: i have given 10 minutes but still i'm getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

You may need to initialize the RestClient before instantiating and calling to `GenerateAccessToken`

```
ZCRMRestClient.initialize();
```

Comment: perhaps the config file (that `initialize` uses) has some small error somewhere. What you did seems to be OK to me. In my experience everything works if: the config data is correct (particularly the client ID, secret and the current user email), you initialize before any operation and the Grant Token has been recently created with proper "permissions" (eg. to work with the CRM: `Aaaserver.profile.READ,ZohoCRM.users.READ,ZohoCRM.modules.ALL`).